# ColdFusion CFHTTP working with data returned from API

Tags: json, coldfusion, rotten-tomatoes

I am just starting to work with the Rotten Tomatoes API to retrieve movie information, and I need some help understanding how to work with the data that is returned. This is my first time working with an API such as this, so please forgive me if this sounds basic.

Using cfhttp I can successfully connect to the API and return search data, but I don't really know what format I am getting back. I thought it was JSON, but using isJSON to check it returns false.  I would like to be able to call individual fields within the returned data to populate a query result set that I can output to the user.

The code I am using to make the call is simple:

```
<cfhttp url="#apiURL#movies.json?apikey=#apiKey#&q=#movieName#" method="get" result="httpResp" timeout="120">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResp#" />
```

And the data that is being returned:

[image: This is how the data looks when returned]

I don't expect anyone to give me a complete walk-through of how to build my app, but if someone could give me some pointers as to the proper way to convert the data into a query result, or something else I can use, I would appreciate it.

Edit:  Didn't realize the image would be so difficult to read, so here's a cut and paste of the data being returned.

```
{"total":2,"movies":[{"id":"11029","title":"Krull","year":1983,"mpaa_rating":"PG","runtime":120,"release_dates":{"theater":"1983-07-29","dvd":"2001-04-03"},"ratings":{"critics_rating":"Rotten","critics_score":33,"audience_rating":"Spilled","audience_score":49},"synopsis":"","posters":{"thumbnail":"http://content6.flixster.com/movie/25/86/258696_mob.jpg","profile":"http://content6.flixster.com/movie/25/86/258696_pro.jpg","detailed":"http://content6.flixster.com/movie/25/86/258696_det.jpg","original":"http://content6.flixster.com/movie/25/86/258696_ori.jpg"},"abridged_cast":[{"name":"Ken Marshall","id":"162668719","characters":["Prince Colwyn"]},{"name":"Lysette Anthony","id":"162668720","characters":["Lyssa"]},{"name":"Freddie Jones","id":"162664678","characters":["Ynyr"]},{"name":"Francesca Annis","id":"162688297","characters":["Widow of the Web"]},{"name":"Alun Armstrong","id":"770670461","characters":["Torquil"]}],"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/11029.json","alternate":"http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/krull/","cast":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/11029/cast.json","clips":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/11029/clips.json","reviews":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/11029/reviews.json","similar":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/11029/similar.json"}},{"id":"770670060","title":"Bekenntnisse des Hochstaplers Felix Krull (Confessions of Felix Krull)","year":1957,"mpaa_rating":"Unrated","runtime":107,"release_dates":{"theater":"1958-03-04"},"ratings":{"critics_score":-1,"audience_rating":"Spilled","audience_score":33},"synopsis":"","posters":{"thumbnail":"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/10/84/16/10841649_mob.jpg","profile":"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/10/84/16/10841649_pro.jpg","detailed":"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/10/84/16/10841649_det.jpg","original":"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/10/84/16/10841649_ori.jpg"},"abridged_cast":[{"name":"Horst Buchholz","id":"162718595","characters":["Felix Krull"]},{"name":"Liselotte Pulver","id":"326392065","characters":["Zaza"]},{"name":"Ingrid Andree","id":"770670669","characters":["Zouzou"]},{"name":"Susi Nicoletti","id":"770670670","characters":["Madame Houpfle"]},{"name":"Paul Dahlke","id":"573372814","characters":["Professor Kuckuck"]}],"alternate_ids":{"imdb":"0050179"},"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770670060.json","alternate":"http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/bekenntnisse-des-hochstaplers-felix-krull-confessions-of-felix-krull/","cast":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770670060/cast.json","clips":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770670060/clips.json","reviews":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770670060/reviews.json","similar":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770670060/similar.json"}}],"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=Krull&page_limit=30&page=1"},"link_template":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q={search-term}&page_limit={results-per-page}&page={page-number}"}
```

**Edit: Thanks, Dan. That was the nudge I needed.  After I understood how to get at the JSON data, I was able to find the following explanation of how to turn it into a useful query:[Work with remote API JSON data in CF](http://www.monkehworks.com/work-with-remote-api-json-data-in-coldfusion-10-queries).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filecontent looks like json.  You can refer to it by using

```
#httpResp.filecontent#.
```

Answer (score 9):

The data needs to be deserialized:

```
<cfset tomatoData=DeserializeJSON(httpResp.filecontent)>

<cfdump var="#tomatoData#">
```

It looks like the first level in has nothing but structs. So you may be able to

```
<cfdump var="#tomatoData.total#"> <!--- A single item --->
<cfdump var="#tomatoData.movies#"> <!--- An array --->
```